# What could make Java crash and skip a try catch block?

Tags: java, android, coronasdk

I am having some issues with Corona SDK, their Android coder claims the bug is in Java or in Android that refuses to catch a exception and instead crash.

I never heard of that before, so, if what they are saying is true, can it be corrected?

My problem in particular: http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/34688-how-i-load-a-16-bit-image

And a summary:

I am trying to load a 2048x2048 image using Corona SDK. I can do it with Marmalade SDK, and with native Java, but with Corona it crashes on Nexus One and Xperia Play (and probably many other untested devices) on Android 2.3

I submitted a bug report to them, and their reply is that they have lots of fallbacks that rely on try catch blocks on their Java code, but that on the devices where it crash, it crashes instead of triggering the catch block, or it silently fails and skips the catch block entirely.

I want to know how to fix that issue (it crashing or skipping instead of triggering the catch block)

Comment: This question would be better if you summarize what your link is about, in case it ever becomes stale (which would make the question on S/O useless)

Comment: Oh I see, I will try to improve the question

Comment: If the block is trying to catch a particular type of exception, but another type occurs, than the application would crash. Can you post the actual error log from those devices that have issues?

Comment: Is the problem that the code is crashing outside of managed Java code? If so, there's no real way you can prevent that from the Java side - either you need to get down and dirty yourself, or find another way.

Comment: I will try to post the error log tomorrow, but the exception that I see in LogCat when the crash happens, or the exception that Corona SDK itself shows on the screen when it does not crash, is OutOfMemory

Comment: To those that nuked my question from orbit, can you help me fix it? This is a VERY SERIOUS issue, I am the co-owner of a startup, and this is blocking further development of a new flagship product, I REALLY, REALLY, REALLY need to fix this! I am desperate, help me for the love of everything, if the question has issues, tell me how to fix the question, because the question must be asked! I must know why the try catch block is not working!

Comment: @speeder - If you want the question reopened, I suggest that you take the time to improve it.  In its current state, it is borderline unanswerable.  And I don't think there's much more that *could* be said that is not already in my Answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, this is not a Java (TM) problem.  It is an Android problem that is related to one or more of the following:

- the generic Android platform (unlikely)
- your phone's specific port of Android, or
- 3rd-party *native code* extensions.

If the problem is the result of a (Davlik) VM crash, then there is nothing that your app can do after the problem has been triggered.  When the DVM crashes, that's "game over".  No exceptions will be caught.  In fact, no more Java code will be executed ... until you restart.

DVM (and JVM) only crashes when the VM gets itself into a state where safe continuation is not possible.  Typically you've got some kind of memory corruption or something that is trigging hardware exceptions (segvs, illegal instructions, etc).  Normal pure Java code can't make this happen ... unless there's a platform bug.  Native code can make it happen.

Who it so blame?

- If Corona includes native code libraries, it is potentially their bug.  Otherwise not.  (If their code is "pure" Java code and a VM crash occurs, they didn't cause it and they can't recover from it.  See above.)
- If you've got other 3rd-party native code active, that's possibly to blame.
- Otherwise, the fault is most likely in the specific port of Android for your device.

What you can do?

- Check to see if Corona includes native code libraries.
- Try looking on the manufacturer's site for bug reports and fixes or workarounds.  (This sounds like it might be a bug in the garbage collection area, but there should be more clues in the crash dump.)
- Get a newer mobile phone.  Sadly, a lot of wireless phone networks are not providing timely updates for older android phones ... if you believe this: http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/04/wireless-carriers-deceptive-and-unfair/
- Complain.  It probably won't help, but it may make you feel better :-)

The workaroound may be to either increase your app's heap allocation (if that is possible) or modify the way that your app works so that it doesn't *try* to load large images into memory in one go.  Lets face it, Android phones don't have huge amounts of memory, and the maximum size of your heap limits what an app can do.  Big images take a LOT of heap space.

**UPDATE**

In the light of the extra context you've provided, I think the workaround approach is best.  Simply don't *attempt* to load huge images.  Find another way.

Comment: One of the crashy phones is Nexus One running Android 2.3... This is the Google reference implementation no?

Comment: I would add a call to System.exit() in any thread.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - now that's an interesting approach.  Wouldn't a glass of water be quicker?

Comment: Native code you mean NDK code?

Comment: @speeder - that's the kind of thing I mean.  (I'm not that familiar with Android ...)

Comment: @StephenC Being pedantic, it could take you a lot of milli-seconds to do that. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Being even more pedantic: ... but considerably less development time :-)

Comment: @StephenC just don't use a micro-wave to dry it out. (I know of someone who did and couldn't get it fixed ;)